# How would I implement idxmax with random tiebreaking on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe like this:

| id | col1 | col2 | idxmax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.0 | 4.0 | col2 |
| 2 | 5.0 | 5.0 | tiebreak |
| 3 | 6.0 | 9.0 | col 2 |

In the case of my example dataframe I'd like to return either col1 or col2 based on whichever name wins the tie. Not including the row ID.

At the moment the `df.idxmax(axis = 1)` function just returns the column name of the column with first max value, as per the documentation. However, to ensure elimination of bias, I'd like to turn this into a random tie break but I genuinely have no idea how to do this.

Could you please help?

Comment: Should the `id` column be considered during the horizontal *comparison* ? Also, note that the idxmax of the first row should be `col2` and not `col1`.

Comment: Good catch thank you! But I wouldn't want the id column to be considered, so I would need to drop that column before doing the comparison I imagine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @Timeless' approach with random sampling, the issue is that it will always use the same tie-breaker for different rows that have the same combination of equal maxes.

An alternative would be to first [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the data:

```
df['idxmax'] = (df
   .drop(columns=['id', 'idxmax'], errors='ignore')
   .stack()
   .sample(frac=1)
   .groupby(level=0).idxmax().str[1]
)
```

Alternatively:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['id', 'idxmax'])

m = df[cols].eq(df[cols].max(axis=1), axis=0)

df['idxmax'] = (m[m].stack().reset_index(1)
                .groupby(level=0)['level_1'].sample(n=1)
               )
```

Example output:

```
   id  col1  col2 idxmax
0   1   3.0   4.0   col2
1   2   5.0   5.0   col2
2   3   6.0   9.0   col2
```

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the shortcomings of my naïve approach :D

Comment: @Timeless it's a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Match each row with its *max* value to further randomly [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) the column name:

```
df['idxmax'] = [np.random.choice(df.columns[r == m]) 
                for r, m in zip(df.values, df.max(1))]
```

---

Sample output:

```
   id  col1  col2 idxmax
0   1   3.0   4.0   col2
1   2   5.0   5.0   col2
2   3   6.0   9.0   col2
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible option would be using [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to *shuffle* the columns order :

```
cols = df.sample(frac=1, axis=1).columns.difference(["id"], sort=False)
 
df["idxmax"] = df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   id  col1  col2 idxmax
0   1   3.0   4.0   col2
1   2   5.0   5.0   col1
2   3   6.0   9.0   col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example dataframe seems slightly wrong since you have col1 as idxmax in the first row even though the value is bigger in col2 than in col1 (4 > 3). However, i think something like this will give the result you desire:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def randargmax(row):
    all_ties = [i for i, val in enumerate(row) if val == row.max()]
    return np.random.choice(all_ties)


df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [3, 5, 6], "col2": [4, 5, 9]})
df["idxmax"] = [df.columns[randargmax(row)] for _, row in df.iterrows()]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

For each row, find the max value, find cells containing it, then get their index and take a random choice. I'm not sure if this can be vectorized, but at least it's easy to write using `apply`:

```
df.assign(idxmax=
    df.apply(lambda row: np.random.choice(row.index[row==row.max()]), axis=1)
)
```

Example output:

```
    col1  col2 idxmax
id                   
1    3.0   4.0   col2
2    5.0   5.0   col2
3    6.0   9.0   col2
```

Comment: P.S. This is very similar to [Roman's answer](/a/77455502/4518341) but a bit more idiomatic.